# C++, How to traverse through a unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map

To summarize my problem, in an "unordered_map" I will be adding a pair, name with a number, and sending it to a function. (function doesn't matter what it does.) So then I will be adding another thing to the graph map, but I want to be able to traverse to the next thing I added to the list because I want to throw mark's name into the function next.

Here is some code

```
unordered_map<string,int> graph;
unordered_map<string,int>:: iterator it;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string name;
    graph.insert(pair<string,int>("Sue",4));    
    it=graph.begin();
    name = it -> first; //name is equal to "Sue"
    function(name);
    graph.insert(pair<string,int>("Mark",83));
    it++ // this will not work
    name = it -> first; //this will not end up equaling to "Mark"
    function(name);
    }
```

Doing `++it` does not work,going backwards `--it`, doesn't work too.

So does anyone have a solution how I can go backwards to obtain the `name = it -> first` to be `Mark`?

Note:  (I will be doing this method multiple times too because it'll be going into a loop.)

Comment: What do you mean by "next thing"? Next in what order?

Comment: @TemplateRex the only thing that I've done is to edit the text. I've never (ever) removed or considered removing a tag. (if something like that happened was unwillingly or you're mistaken)

Comment: @simplicisveritatis well, the edit history shows that you removed it, but no problem if it was by accident!

Answer (score 3):

For `unordered_map`, it's not guaranteed that an item inserted after another item, will also be stored after that item. This is what is meant with an *unordered* map.

In this case, you are out of luck: the `std::hash<std::string>` conspires to let "Sue" come after "Mark" and `it++` points to `graph.end()` and `it->first` is dereferencing this, with a memory error.

If you would use an *ordered* `map<string, int>` and insert "Sue" after "Mark" (or you would use `std::greater` as the `map` comparison for your original order of "Mark" after "Sue"), then the order of elements is what you expect.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
map<string,int> graph;
map<string,int>:: iterator it;

int main()
{
    string name;
    graph.insert(pair<string,int>("Mark",4));    
    it=graph.begin();
    name = it -> first; //name is equal to "Sue"
    std::cout << name;
    graph.insert(pair<string,int>("Sue",83));
    it++ ;// this will not work
    name = it -> first; //this will not end up equaling to "Mark"
    std::cout << name;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3841a75954d6ec3).

Answer (score -1):

I think this is because the iterator values are generated when you call `Begin()`.

In some other languages (C#) if a `IEnumerable` (e.g. `List`) changes while an `IEnumerator` (aka. iterator) is active, the `Enumerator` becomes invalid
and the following `IEnumerator::MoveNext()` will throw an `InvalidOperationException`.
see [MSDN Article on IEnumerator.MoveNext Method()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also [This article on CPPReference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) states:

> If rehashing occurs due to the insertion, all iterators are invalidated. Otherwise iterators are not affected. References are not invalidated. Rehashing occurs only if the new number of elements is equal to or greater than max_load_factor()*bucket_count().